# what is the meaning of いくわけだ

Tags: grammar, translation

From a passage saying that it's hard for people to visualize or grasp the scale of things when they're in expressed in units they can't easily relate to- but that if something people can relate to is used people can get an idea more easily. The sentence I'm unsure about is:

例えば、「東京ドーム５。７杯分」と書けば、「ああ、そんなに多いのか」と納得がいくわけだ。

'For example. if it's written that Tokyo Dome is the equivalent of 5.7 glasses(??), then people can get an idea of the scale, thinking 'ooh its that big is it'. - Is my understanding of that.

I understand 'wake' and 'iku' seperately as reasoning, and go respectively. However, when they're together here, does it basically mean, 'goes the reasoning'? Or is there a different nuance going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

～は納得が行く is a set phrase that means:

1. ～ makes sense; ～ sounds convincing; one is satisfied by ～

   > その説明は納得が行きません。もっと詳しく話してください。
   >   納得の行く説明が欲しい。
2. ～ is satisfied (by an explanation); ～ is convinced (by something)

   > 彼はまだ納得が行かないようだ。
   >   あなたが納得が行くまで、何度でも教えます。

This usage of 行く is described as the tenth definition of [this entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/225173/meaning/m0u/), but practically you'll have to [memorize this rather than analyze this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42909/8629).

訳【わけ】 means *reason*. ～わけだ means "it's natural to think ～", "no wonder ～", "therefore ～", "as a natural consequence, ～", etc.

> 「ああ、そんなに多いのか」と納得がいくわけだ。
>   (saying it) will naturally make sense to you — "Ah, it's that much!"